# Push Woosh and PhoneGap 2.5.0 implimentation

Tags: javascript, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I have tried every which way to impliment the code here:

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

and I am failing.  I have it enabled on the backend, I follow all of these instrucitons to the best of my ability...my profile is enabled in app developer portale, but for the life of me I am failing....I think I am failing here:

```
function initPushwoosh() {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.onDeviceReady();

pushNotification.registerDevice({alert:true, badge:true, sound:true, pw_appid:"PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID", appname:"APP_NAME"},
    function(status) {
        var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
        console.warn('registerDevice: ' + deviceToken);
    },
    function(status) {
        console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
        navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
    }
);

pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);

document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
    var notification = event.notification;
    navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
});
```

}

I made sure I put this in my index.js, and I made sure I put in my appcode and app name to match the pooshwoosh backend portal, but I still am failing...any insite WOULD BE AMAZING!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in your XCode console logs? Do you receive push notifications token? Also do you see any subscribers in the control panel?

First thing to check is that your mobileprovisioning profile has push enabled. Look for "aps-environment" string in it. Also note that gateway settings in the Pushwoosh Control Panel must match the profile: "Sandbox" for "development" profiles and "Production" for Ah-Hoc and AppStore builds.

The good place to start is the sample project here:
https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK%20Sample%20Projects/iPhone-Phonegap